# L shaped shelf pin -can it be installed in the reversed position?

Tags: shelving

This is the pin that I am asking about
If you install it like in the picture there will be a gap between the edge of the shelf and the side panel of the bookcase.

I would like to install it with the bottom of the L up but I don't want to secure the pin to the shelf board with a screw (so I can later reposition the shelf without a headache

Considering that four of these would support a shelf I don't think that they can pivot in any way if they are not secured. Am I wrong ?

[image]

Update:
This could be a solution install them upside down and join them with a strip of wood from under the L
[image]

Comment: You would need to size the boards to match - i.e., perhaps 1/4" wider than they would otherwise be. If they are not "full width" then not only will you have not removed the gap, but the boards will actually be subject to sliding around with all their contents...which is not a good thing. On the other hand, if you are building this totally from scratch then you can use a different type of pin that is designed differently and avoids the gap problem.

Comment: Bought a bag of these a long time ago. I am planning to use a stair tread gauge to get the precise size.  I just realized I could screw each pair of pins to a strip of wood -see the update to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quality full-concealed job where the shelf *can't* slide but *can* be easily repositioned use a router to put a recess in the end and bottom of the shelf that fits the shelf supports. No gap, and the shelf locks in place when the shelf sets in, but can be lifted up for repositioning.

An alternate but more visible (you see the slot) method is to route a shallow strip over the row of holes that the pins go into, which takes the face of the pins flush with the inside of the bookshelf.

Either method allows full length shelves with no gap.

The method you have illustrated has the downside of blocking the upper corner of the shelf below, which matters or doesn't depending on how you are using the shelves. If you have a shelf-full of books of one size, you either get more of a gap above them to clear that obstruction, or you need smaller books at the ends of the shelf. That might not matter with a shelf used for non-book items or many sizes of book (so long as the arrangement on the shelf allows for small ones on the end.)

Comment: it will be used for tools so probably that strip is fine. If I grab the router for these then I won't need the pins amore I would have the slots deep enough to support the shelves. The issue with that approach is that unlike the pin holes the resolution (the increment) for the slots is much bigger than for the holes

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install them upside down.

With a little weight on the shelf they are not likely to rotate.  To be more secure add a little wood to the hole. Something very small like the tip of a tooth pick. Tap the bracket in with a hammer if needed.

Comment: Or, better, drive a screw through the hole into the bottom of the shelf... which is what that hole is for. Of course you then have to remove the screws if you want to change the shelf position.

Comment: " I don't want to secure the pin to the shelf"  Op does not consider that an option.

Comment: True, @RMDman, but sometimes if you want "A", you just gotta do "B" or it may not work out the way you want it to...